# event.preventDefault() doesn't work with link

Tags: javascript

i am working on a project for university and i seem to have a problem.
it is supposed to play a sound clip when the user clicks on a place on the map
this is my code:

```js
// Container to retrieve all hyperlinks within map overlay (points of interest)
var markers = document.querySelectorAll('.mapOverlay a');

// Constructor for new audio component for playback
var audioPlayer = new Audio();

// Iterate through all found markers
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

  // Add CLICK event handler to each point
  markers[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    // Cancel actual hyperlink request
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get audio source file from hyperlink
    var audioSrc = this.getAttribute("href");

    // If this point is already playing the audio, stop it and exit
    if (!audioPlayer.paused && audioPlayer.src === audioSrc) {
      audioPlayer.pause();
      return;
    }

    // Set audio player source
    audioPlayer.src = audioSrc;

    // Play audio file
    audioPlayer.play();

  });

}
```

```css
/* World Map Image / Container */

#WorldMap {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000 url(https://i.imgur.com/HnEMwm1.png) top left no-repeat;
}


/* Overlay Hyperlink (Point of Interest Base) */

.mapOverlay a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
}


/* Specific Point of Interest - Washington D.C. */

.mapOverlay a.point1 {
  left: 190px;
  top: 270px;
  background-color: pink;
}


/* Specific Point of Interest - Japan */

.mapOverlay a.point2 {
  left: 675px;
  top: 270px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.mapOverlay a.point3 {
  left: 300;
  top: 400;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>World Map</title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link src="javascript.js" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="WorldMap">
    <div class="mapOverlay">
      <a class="point1" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/61/I_Have_A_Dream_sample.ogg"></a>
      <a class="point2" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3d/7_sample.ogg"></a>
      <a class="point3" href="sounds/test.ogg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that i dont want to open the link, just have the audio clip play. However `event.preventDefault();` doesn't work and the link opens.

Also for some reason the code snippet seems to work when i placed it here

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Consider using a `data-src` attribute instead of the `href` attribute. Then you don't need to worry about it navigating.

Comment: Since it works here, there's likely other code which is causing this problem.

Comment: It works when tested. Check your console if it is hitting any other errors.

Comment: I just made a fiddle and it seems to work fine.